# Всем привет! Нужна помощь с поиском процента от БОЛЬШИХ (BigInt) чисел в JavaScript!

Tags: javascript, node.js, biginteger

Многие варианты перепробовал: самостоятельно пытался искать решение, юзать либы, но всё безуспешно. С небольшими числами проблем нет, однако если брать числа большие, тут-то и начинаются проблемы:

Например, попытка через mathjs:

```
const usedSize = 1730434322222;

const percentOfUsed = divide(multiply(bignumber(usedSize), 100),bignumber(size));

console.log(percentOfUsed.toString());
```

**Результат**: *1.611592547989837844607500921137822419400672445327161308198615409e-11*

Если поиграться с переменной useSize, то начало будет таким же 1.61159.... Будет изменяться лишь конец: с -11 до -10, -9 и так далее.

Как же тогда найти нормальное решение? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Пропустил так же ещё переменную size:
`const size = 10737418241232222212312123;`

Comment: Всё в порядке. У вас такой маленький процент, что у него впереди одиннадцать нулей после запятой. То что вы видите - показательная (научная) запись числа. Только число очень мало. Примерно 1.6 * 10^-11.